# Errors during concurrent database access - Race conditions?

Tags: c#, sql, mariadb, race-condition

We're having trouble with our application that is used by nearly 500 people at the same time. It's a windows desktop application that uses a single database in the background to store the data. From time to time there seem to be some race conditions we cannot reproduce. When updating the wrong ID is selected and so the wrong data is updated for example.

```
protected static void ExecuteNonQuery(MySqlConnection connection, String statement, OptionalOut<int> outResult = null)
{
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    var cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = statement;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;

    MySqlTransaction tran = null;
    MySqlDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {

        connection.Open();
        tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (statement.ToUpper().StartsWith("INSERT INTO"))
        {
            if (outResult == null) outResult = new OptionalOut<int>();
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS last_ID";
            cmd2.CommandTimeout = 30;
            reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            var ret = ConvertToDataSet(reader);
            var cells = ret.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
            outResult.Result = Convert.ToInt32(cells);
            reader.Close();
        }
        tran.Commit();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (reader != null && !reader.IsClosed)
            reader.Close();
        if (tran != null && connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed && connection.State != ConnectionState.Broken)
            tran.Rollback();

        connection.Close();

        throw;
    }
}
```

Is there a problem with this method? Do I need some additional locking mechanism or should the parameter `IsolationLevel.Serializable` be enough? What do I have to do to prevent every possible scenario for race conditions?

EDIT: Another strange problem is that when a row is being updated and something is failing, other columns are changed though not being affected. This happens randomly, the SQL in general works fine!

For example a client gets an offer (offer is foreign key in client table), the offer state switches from `None` to `OfferReceived`. An employee accepts the offer and saves, client row in database has no offer anymore and offer state is switched to `OfferAccepted`. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: If you debug two applications in two VS instances; where do the second application wait for the lock to be released? If the second application waits on ExecuteNonQuery it could probably have an old value for last_ID and when the lock is released it is inserted.

Comment: I'm not sure how transactions work in MySQL but I'm thinking that the first client inserts a row, and before the first client updates last_ID the second client tries to do an insert using the old value and when lock is released the insert is done with the old id. But my theory only works if last_ID is used for the new row?

Comment: Are you sure that the insert was successful?  I don't see any checks for this before you read Last_Insert_ID.

Comment: A couple of points not relevant to your problem:  You can use an ExecuteScalor() to get the last_insert_id() rather than a reader, because it will only return one value.  And the database should not be opened and closed every time you need to execute against the DB, this is very costly action.  Open it when the app starts, and close it when the app closes is better.

Comment: The problem seems not be timing related, we encountered dirty reads though the row wasn't touched within days...the insert should work I think because otherwise `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` should throw and a rollback should be done. Btw I inserted a missing `throw` in the catch block.

Comment: The insert statement can run successfully but not insert any data, and hence this would not throw an exception.  So you should check the return value of ExecuteNonQuery to see how many rows were affected,   This can depend on your SQL statement (which you have not included in your example).

Comment: Wasn't aware of that...this could explain wrong `SELECT_LAST_ID`, I'll check that, thx!

Comment: Please provide the SQL statements generated by your code.  Some of us are not familiar with the mapping from C# to SQL.